# how to pass the disabled dates in react-date-range

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I would like to know how to pass the disabled dates.
the dates will be all those **that are not in the state availableDates**
This component will be used to save the booking of travel.

```
'use client';

import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  DateRange,
  Range,
  RangeKeyDict
} from 'react-date-range';

import 'react-date-range/dist/styles.css';
import 'react-date-range/dist/theme/default.css';

interface DatePickerProps {
  value: Range,
  onChange: (value: RangeKeyDict) => void;

}

const DatePicker: React.FC<DatePickerProps> = ({
  value,
  onChange,
}) => {

  **const [availableDates, setAvailableDates] = useState<string[]>([]);**

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchAvailableDates() {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/booking"
      );
      setAvailableDates(response.data.availableDates);
    }

    fetchAvailableDates();
  }, []);

  return (
    <DateRange
      rangeColors={['#262626']}
      ranges={[value]}
      date={new Date()}
      onChange={onChange}
      direction="vertical"
      showDateDisplay={false}
      minDate={new Date()}
      **disabledDates={[]}**
    />
  );
}

export default DatePicker
```

I am not able to see a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case you need to use disabledDay prop.
Added the code you need at the end of your source code.

```
 <DateRange
      rangeColors={['#262626']}
      ranges={[value]}
      date={new Date()}
      onChange={onChange}
      direction="vertical"
      showDateDisplay={false}
      minDate={new Date()}
      **disabledDates={[]}**
      disabledDay={(date) => !availableDates.includes(date)}
    />
```